# Laravel 5 View is loading from cache and new code not affecting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have been working in my Vagrant development environment and the Laravel 5 app is working fine. When I uploaded the app to my DO Ubuntu 14.14 droplet, its loading the View from cache and when I update the view blade template, its not affecting the site.

I've searched for solution but didn't found anything. Now sure how to stop caching the view or refresh the cache.

**Error:**

```
ErrorException in 61093154cb848bf7f33155b09ac70c93 line 132: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$profile_picture (View: /var/www/demo/property/public/resources/views/user/account/acc.blade.php)

    in 61093154cb848bf7f33155b09ac70c93 line 132
    at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 43
    at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/demo/property/public/storage/framework/views/61093154cb848bf7f33155b09ac70c93', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'page_title' => 'User Account', 'profile' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 57
    at CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/demo/property/public/resources/views/user/account/acc.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'page_title' => 'User Account', 'profile' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 136
    at View->getContents() in View.php line 104
    at View->renderContents() in View.php line 78
    at View->render() in Response.php line 44
    at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 202
    at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1198
    at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 702
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 47
    at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 703
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

After the error, I've updated the line 132 but its not affecting. I tried by removing all content from the acc.blade.php file but still I get the error.

Comment: What do you mean with "cache"? you mean the temp file that laravel build for your view in storage's folder? what if you try deleting that temp file?

Comment: @CarlosHerreraPlata I've added the error in my description. I hope it will help to understand. I didn't try to delete the files in temp folder as I am not sure will that break anything or something like that.

Comment: run `php artisan cache:clear` to clear your cache on your server

Comment: well try deleting the file `61093154cb848bf7f33155b09ac70c93.php` it would be stored in: `/storage/framework/views`

Comment: I tried `php artisan cache:clear` and deleting files from the `storage/framework/views` folder... but it didn't worked before.. but when I do both and go back to the site, it seems working. Thanks people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a package (artisan command) for clearing views because it was really annoying to clear them manually.

https://github.com/Kyslik/view-clear

when installed just `$ php artisan view:clear`

#### If you are using Laravel 5.1.* you don't need this package since it is part of Laravel base commands.

---

Perhaps browser itself is doing some caching, so use "hard reload" or "hard refresh" using ctrl+f5 (ctrl+r) on windows or shift+command+r on osx.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because I am using your package which I got from NPM. Though I need to run `php artisan cache:clear` before your `view:clear` but still it helps a lot as I don't need to go and choose every file and remove them. If you can add some parameter like `view:clear --cc` with will execute `cashe:clear` automatically, that would be great.

Comment: I will look into it, next time try to comment right in github ;). Good luck Artisan.

Comment: @ArifulHaque does order of execution `view:clear`, `cache:clear` matter?

Comment: I maintained `cache:clear` > `view:clear` but didn't check the reverse order.